# UIDocument save error: Could not get attribute values

Tags: ios, ios11, uidocument

I see this error in Xcode debug console when I call `save(...)` on my `UIDocument`, but it seems to have no effect on my app. Anyone know what causes it and how to stop it? I'm saving documents as a package with `FileWrapper`.

> 2018-08-12 10:24:12.818324-0400 MyApp[2694:1486251] [default] [ERROR]
>      Could not get attribute values for item /private/var/[...]/Documents/NewDoc.myextension (s).
>   Error: Error Domain=LocalStorageFileProvider.LocalFileProviderError Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, I haven't.  -